# html br tag in text element - how to display it as text

Tags: html, tags, line-breaks

This is a little question to which i couldn't find an answer by searching.
I have this text which says: `<p>Each <br> tag represents a new line break</p>`, and i want the br tag to be visible as text instead of a line break.

Comment: Replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you nikhil, for giving me the answer.
The answer is:

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

`&lt;` represents <

and

`&gt;` represents >